# Qual SCRIPT em Postgres para listar todos os Schemas?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Preciso saber qual script utilizo para me listar todos so Schemas de um Banco de Dados ?
1 Condição é listar todos os Schemas que eu criei e não preciso dos Schemas do Postgres
Preciso dessa informação para poder gerar permissões de acessos aos usuários automaticamente a todos os schemas através de uma Function

Answer (score 1):

Este comando simples vai retornar para voce os schemas que voce criou no banco de dados mais o schema public

```
select 
    schema_name
from 
    information_schema.schemata
where
    schema_name !~ '^pg_' AND 
    schema_name <> 'information_schema'
```